# Unable to find wireless Display option in windows optional features on windows 10

Tags: windows

i am using windows 10 and wants to mirror my screen on my pc/laptop through it. when i bought my laptop i was able to connect but after reinstallation of windows i failed to find Microsoft Connect app. i tried other sources and by Google i got that i can enable

> Wireless Display Option
> in windows optional features but there was no any option like wireless display.

do anyone know how to get it?

[image: no optional feature for wireless display]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after searching for several sites and blogs, i got my solutions.
i just opened my command prompt (or you can use powershell too) in Administratior mode and pasted the command i found on this site:

[install wireless display option with command prompt](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/157692-install-uninstall-connect-wireless-display-feature-windows-10-a.html#option2)

and here is the code :

```
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:App.WirelessDisplay.Connect~~~~0.0.1.0
```

now i am again able to use wireless display option in my windows 10.

thanks to the author.